# Suppose $f$ is differentiable and $f^\prime(x) = 0$, then $f(x) = o(x)$ at $x\rightarrow 0$?

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, derivatives, notation

I know there are two ways to understand $o(x)$, in this case we only discuss in the situation of $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac {f(x)}{g(x)}=0 \Longleftrightarrow f(x) = o(g)$

So I wonder whether it is true that $f$ is differentiable and $f^\prime(x) = 0$, then $f(x) = o(x)$ at $x\rightarrow 0$

Could anyone give me some hints on this question?

Comment: $f(x)=1$ is a counterexample.

Comment: You would need $f(0) = 0$ as well as $f'(0) = 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint** Use the definition of the derivative...

$$0 = f'(0)= \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x}$$

Now see what happens if $f(0)=0$ or $f(0) \neq 0$.

Comment: Sorry, I am kinda confused. I remember the definition of derivative is $0 = f^\prime(0) = \lim_{h\rightarrow 0} \frac {f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$. How did you get that?

Comment: To get $f(0)$ your $x$ is $0.$ Thus $f'(0) = \lim_{h\rightarrow 0} \frac {f(h)-f(0)}{h}.$ Note that for any $x$ it is  $f^\prime(x) = \lim_{h\rightarrow 0} \frac {f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}.$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** It might be easier to see what’s going on if you work with the definition of the differential instead of the derivative, i.e., $f(x+h)-f(x)= h\,\mathrm df(x)+o(h)$.